# Curie temperature and magnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, temperature, phase-transition, ferromagnetism

What would happen to the magnetic property of a ferromagnetic material if it is heated above the *Curie temperature*, and then cooled down below it?

Answer (score 0):

The material regains its magnetic properties.  There are demonstrations of this in some science museums (sadly, I can't track down which have such an exhibit).